# Displaying the total sum of values from strings

Tags: string, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

My project is a simple shopping game where the user types in the quantity amount, and the value of the individual prices appears and then a total sum can appear below.

I have managed to create the part of displaying the individual product price but i am confused on how to add the total sum and display correctly at the instance that i defined.

**Some info**

Actionscript will check for keypress event

sample of code snippet:

```
    if(e.keyCode == 49){ //1
    trace("Key Code Pressed: " + e.keyCode);
    amount1.text = "1.00"
    }
```

...

```
    var total:Number = amount1+ amount2+amount3+amount4+amount5;
    output1.text = String(total);
```

From the code above, when the user types 1, the price will change to "1.00" on the price instance field (dynamic text type).

Picture below:

[image]

A sample of my game running:
[image]

Total price should be $13.00 dollars..

Is there any way to make this happen? I believe is it something to do with `parseint`.

Comment: Have you considered storing the value in a separate variable as an int? Then you don't need to worry about parsing it, and the complexity that introduces?

Comment: Hi, you mean at my key press code, amount1.text = "1.00", i store it as a int instead of a string?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. Still store amount1.text if you need it, but maybe also store amount1value = 1 or something similar

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply! i've tried and have obtained an error when i run my flash movie.. i tried something like amount1.text = 1.00;

Comment: amount1.text will need to be a string as you have it in your example. But you should be able to store the value in a separate variable.

Comment: Can you show us the code that tries to display the total?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to string together multiple `parseint` statements like this:

```
var total:number = parseint(amount1.text) + parseint(amount2.text) + parseint(amount3.text) + parseint(amount4.text) + parseint(amount5.text);
output1.text = total;
```

If you go this route, you will need to handle stituations that involve NaN

Here is the documentation on `parseint` if you haven't already, you should look at it. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000590.html